# Proving that a theorem is invalid ($\left(A\cap B\right)\triangle C\subset \left(A\triangle C\right)\cap \left(B\triangle C\right)$)

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Is this a valid way to show that the theorem is incorrect?

Theorem: $\left(A\cap B\right)\triangle C\subset \left(A\triangle C\right)\cap \left(B\triangle C\right)$
Suppose $a\in \left(A\cap B\right)\triangle C$. Then either $a\in C\setminus \left(A\cap B\right)$ or $a\in \left(A\cap B\right)\setminus C$. Consider the case where $a\in C\setminus \left(A\cap B\right)$, this means $a\in C$ and either $a\notin A$ or $a\notin B$. Consider the case where $a\notin A$ and $a\in B$. Then $a\in B$ and $a\in C$, but this contradicts $a\in(B\triangle C)$.
Thus, the theorem is invalid.

Comment: To prove that such a statement is false you must provide a counterexample...

Comment: If a statement is false or invalid then it's not a theorem. Instead of talking of an "invalid theorem" you should talk about a false statement.

Answer (score 1):

Take

$$A=\{1,2,3\}\,,\,\,B=\{1,2\}\,,\,\,C=\{3\}$$

then

$$(A\cap B)\Delta C=\{1,2\}\Delta \{3\}=\{1,2,3\}$$

yet

$$\left(A\Delta C\right)\cap\left(B\Delta C\right)=\{1,2\}\cap\{1,2,3\}=\{1,2\}$$

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is a draft.
You have shown that
an element $a$ such that $a\in C$ and $a\not\in A$ and $a\in B$
satisfies $a\in (A\cap B)\triangle C$ and $a\not\in (A\triangle C)\cap (B\triangle C)$.
However, this does not immediately show that $(A\cap B)\triangle C\subset (A\triangle C)\cap (B\triangle C)$ is false,
because such an element $a$ may not exist.
You need to also show that an element with this property exists for some sets $A$, $B$, $C$.
The simplest way to do it is to find an explicit example like what @DonAntonio did.

In fact, after you have found a counterexample,
the draft is not necessarily needed to show that the statement is false (although it might be more explanatory to include them,
provided you state clearly what you are trying to show).

---

By the way, the word *theorem* is used to refer to a statement that is true.
Use the word *proposition* or *statement* for a sentence that can be true or false, but not necessarily known to be true or false.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to carry out a proof building a counterexample, then you must investigate the general case and not just for one admitted part $a\in C\setminus \left(A\cap B\right)$, but also for $a\in \left(A\cap B\right)\setminus C$ , because "or" can be true depending on each of them. So, I suggest to consider following:

$$x\in \left(A\cap B\right)\triangle C\Leftrightarrow \\
\Leftrightarrow \Big[x \in A \land x\in B\land x\notin C \Big] \lor \Big[x \in C \land \neg(x \in A \land x\in B ) \Big] \Leftrightarrow \\
\Leftrightarrow \Big[x \in A \land x\in B\land x\notin C \Big] \lor \Big[x \in C \land (x \notin A \lor  x \notin B ) \Big]  \Leftrightarrow \\
 \Big[x \in A \land x\in B\land x\notin C \Big] \lor \Big[x \in C \land x \notin A \Big] \lor \Big[x \in C  \land x \notin B \Big]\ \ (1)$$
From obtained $3$ square brackets cases you should consider all $3$, not only one from them, because, sorry for repetition, "or" can be true depending on each of them.

Right side of implication we can (check it, please) wrote as
$$x \in \left(A\triangle C\right)\cap \left(B\triangle C\right) \Leftrightarrow \\ \Leftrightarrow
\Big[ x \in A \land x\in B\land x\notin C\Big] \lor \Big[ x \notin A \land x\notin B\land x\in C\Big] \ \ (2)$$

So, if we find one such case, where is possible to $(1)$ to be true, when  $(2)$ is false, then we say $(2)$ is not following from $(1)$ and we need to build existing example for this case. What you did is only writing plan how to proof, not looking in details, but it missed implementation, real example.

For example: suppose second square bracket case is true i.e.
$(\exists x)(x \in C \land x \notin A )$ is true. Immediately follows that $(2)$ is false. Now, all the rest is we need "alive" example.

Btw, DonAntonio, in his answer, brought counterexample exactly based on this case.